# How to limit MySQL result according to the values in resultset?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a PHP script for maintaining user information, register new user, and login to secure pages. And for that I have a MySQL table **user** which stores all the information about a user. **User** table has different fields like userid, username, usergroup_id, email_hash, country etc.

In my script, I want to fetch 10 users from each usergroup_id.
What will be the SQL query for this?

Comment: What you have tried? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function, check it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: you Question is not clear can you share me more information about this scenario

Comment: In user table, usergroup_id field contains values from 1 to 5, which is a unique identifier for identifying usergroups. All i want to fetch from user table is, 10 users from each usergroup. That means 10 users from usergroup_id = 1, 10 users from usergroup_id=2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `LIMIT` clause.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.

> Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall
>   within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of
>   results, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is phrased as Limit
>   X, Y and included at the end of your query. X is the starting point
>   (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many
>   records to display).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work for fetching a random set of 10 users for each user group:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.userid in (select userid
                   from user
                   where u.usergroupid = user.usergroupid
                   limit 10
                  )
```

This is using a correlated subquery to limit the row count to 10 for each user group.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one,

```
SELECT c.* FROM customers c where c.id in (select c2.id from customers c2 where c.group_id=c2.group_id limit 0, 10)
```